# how to set a relation with empty value?

Tags: php, yii

I have 2 tables namely **Equipment** and **Supply.**

I have used **array_merge** in yii php to serve as union for two different tables for the purpose of diplaying them in a **single grid**.

Everything works fine with the fields that is common with the two tables. The problem is when I try to display a field that is only existing in one of these two tables. It says **Property "Supply.equipType"** is not defined" because only equipment has the equipType relation.

in my gridView:

```
array(
     'name'=>'equipment_type',
     'value'=>'$data->equipType->name',  
     ),
```

in my controller where I did the merging:

```
    $prov1 = new CActiveDataProvider('BaseEiEquipItem', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                    'condition' => 'id>0'
                    )));

    $prov2 = new CActiveDataProvider('BaseSiReceivedItem', array(
            'criteria' => array(
                    'condition' => 'id>0'
                    )));



    $records=array_merge($prov1->data , $prov2->data);

    $provAll = new CArrayDataProvider($records,
            array(
                    'sort' => array( //optional and sortring
                            'keyField'=>false,
                            'attributes' => array(
                                    'id', 'description',),
                    ),
                    'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10) //optional add a pagination
            )
    );

    $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
            'searchModel'=>$searchModel,
            'modelGrid'=>$modelGrid,
            'provAll' => $provAll,
    ));
```

in my equipment model :

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.      
    return array(
    'equipType' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BaseRefEquipmentType', 'equipment_type'),

    );
}
```

Any idea on how to solve this? Is there any way to fake a relation or something?

thanks in advance

Comment: I already put my codes sir @EmilioGort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add condition to check if equipType is there:

```
'value'=>'isset($data->equipType) ? $data->equipType->name : ""'
```

Using sql to merge results would be better, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use plain SQL union?

If Equipment has 2 fields (a, b) and Supply has 2 fields (b, c), you can do union like this:

```
SELECT a, b, null FROM Equipment
UNION ALL
SELECT null, b, c FROM Supply
```

Comment: can you provide me complete codes for grid,model and controller to implement this sql? I have previously encountered problems using csqldataprovider because I can't find complete codes for it.

Comment: Ahh., come to think of it, the provider is already working sir @leonardys.. The only problem is the relations i use to display a field in grid..

Answer (score 0):

This problem shows, that it's probably not a good idea to mix different model types in one gridview. If you have a model that has no `equipType` then it's pretty obvious, that you can't show this column in a gridview. So what would you expect?

As a (dirty) workaround you can add all missing columns as pseudo attributes to the models where they are missing:

```
public $equipType;
```